# How to specify generic type of a function used in useMemo as argument?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, generics, react-redux

I have generic function that is selector creator used by multiple components (according to https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors) as follows:

```js
const makeCharSelector = <Subscriptions extends UseCharSubscriptions>() =>
    createSelector<[RootStore, string[]], SelectorState<Subscriptions>>(
        [
            (state: RootStore) => ({
                hasChar: state.user.checked && state.user.authenticated && state.user.data.hasChar,
                initialized: state.char.meta.initialized,
            }),
            (state: RootStore, subscriptions: string[]): CharSelectorState<Subscriptions> => {
                const subs = castArray(subscriptions);
                return zipObjectDeep(subs, at(state.char, subs)) as CharSelectorState<Subscriptions>;
            },
            {
                path: 1,
                argIndex: 2,
            },
        ],
        (basic: SelectorState<Subscriptions>, subscriptions: CharSelectorState<Subscriptions>) => {
            basic.char = subscriptions;
            return basic;
        }
    );
```

and then inside a custom hook I am using it like this:

```js
export function useChar<Subscriptions extends UseCharSubscriptions = DefaultSubscriptionsList>(
    subscriptions: string[] = defaultSubscriptions
): CharSelectorState<Subscriptions> | null {
    const selector = useMemo(makeCharSelector, []);
    const state = useSelector((state: RootStore) => selector(state, subscriptions));
```

but then it wrong infers `makeCharSelector` `Subscriptions` generic so I would like to specify it manually by using component `Subscriptions`.

The problem is that I can't write it like this:

```js
useMemo(makeCharSelector<Subscriptions>, [])
```

neither by using `useMemo` generic because it only specifies return type.

So the question is how to properly pass `Subscriptions` generic from `useChar` hook to `makeCharSelector` function?

Comment: Not sure I understand - the type you care about in `useMemo` _is_ the return value, not the signature of the memoization function.

Comment: The thing is I want to specify proper `Subscriptions` generic in `makeCharSelector`, the one from (for example) `useChar<ThisGeneric>` hook call. So I want to supply to `makeCharSelector` `ThisGeneric` something like `makeCharSelector<ThisGeneric>`

Comment: Question: Why does `makeCharSelector ` take a generic type parameter at all? You do not have any function parameters that use it. So maybe use UseCharSubscriptions instead and omit the generics.

Comment: @ford04 because I need `Subscriptions` to be passed to `createSelector<[RootStore, string[]], SelectorState<Subscriptions>>` (second generic specify return type of `createSelector`) which is then used to calculate `state` type here: `state = useSelector((state: RootStore) => selector(state, subscriptions))`

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. The wrapping function looked to me as it would add unnecessary complexity with the generic acting more like a simple type cast. I think, you want to keep the hook clean here, so you could write it like this (hope the return type fits): `const selector = useMemo<Selector<[RootStore, string[]], SelectorState<Subscriptions>>>(makeCharSelector, []);`

Comment: @ford04 Thanks, that's actually a really good idea and solves that problem. I ended up using re-reselect cause selectorator has a really unituitive API, but from what I tested on this solution while still using selectorator, it works as expected.